# Cannot add function in Emacs

Tags: emacs, command

I have recently started using Emacs and I am trying to add a function that will split the entered sentence into a list of words (split by one space):

```
(defun split-by-one-space (string)    ; from: http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html
        "Returns a list of substrings of string
        divided by ONE space each.
        Note: Two consecutive spaces will be seen as
        if there were an empty string between them."
    (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
          as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
          collect (subseq string i j)
          while j))

(defun myfn (ss)
    "documentation of fn: to be added"
    (interactive "s\Enter some words: ")
    (message "Read: %s" (split-by-one-space ss)))
```

I have kept above in folder `~/.emacs.d/init.el` in which there are 2 other functions also which are properly picked up and executed. The above function `'myfn'`, however, is not found when I try to execute it with `M-x` method. The function `'split-by-one-space'` is also not found.

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

### Edit:

Starting Emacs with command "`emacs --debug-init`" shows that following error:

```
(invalid-read-syntax "#")
```

Apparently `\#Space` not recognized in Emacs Lisp. I replaced it with `'?\ '` and this error went away. The function myfn is now available for executing. However, on executing it, following error is shown:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: loop
```

Apparently the loop part needs to be rewritten in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: That `SPLIT-BY-ONE-SPACE` is Common Lisp, not Emacs Lisp.

Comment: `M-x` will only find [interactive functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html). Use `M-:` to execute arbitrary elisp.

Comment: @Juancho: but it *is* interactive.

Comment: How do you know the file is being (re)loaded? What happens if you visit it and do `M-x load-file RET`?

Comment: I have restarted Emacs many times but it has not helped. It did not work even after rebooting the computer.

Comment: What does `C-h v user-init-file` tell you? If that is as expected, do you *also* have an `init.elc` file?

Comment: It shows: `user-init-file is a variable defined in C source code. Its value is "~/.emacs.d/init.el"`

Comment: `(require 'cl)` will provide `loop`. Or alternatively use `(require 'cl-lib)` and `cl-loop`

Comment: Now the error is: `Wrong type argument: sequencep, str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#\Space` is not valid Elisp and will cause a read-error, so most Emacs will stop processing your file at this point.  You want to write `?\s` or `?\` instead, which is the syntax used in Elisp for character literals.

After that, you'll see that `loop` is not known to Emacs.  You want to use `cl-loop` instead, which is provided by the `cl-lib` package, so not only you need to rename `loop` to `cl-loop` but you additionally need to add

```
(require 'cl-lib)
```

earlier.  Similarly `subseq` and `positions` are not known to Elisp and you'll need to use `cl-subseq` and `cl-position` instead (also provided by `cl-lib`).

Comment: Please see the edit in my question and discussion in comments. It does not work even after correction of space character correction.

Comment: @mso: Yes, Elisp is not Common Lisp, so your code has many problems.  I added further details for the problems I could foresee.

Comment: I also found 'split-string' which seems to be a part of emacs lisp!